# OpenGLES headers including Availability.h prevents CPP files from compiling

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, compilation, include

I'm working on something using OpenGLES in Xcode - it's primarily for use on iOS, but I was hoping to make the OpenGLES portion C++ only, independent in that it doesn't use ObjectiveC. However the OpenGLES includes seem to be importing something that requires Objective-C (Availability.h), so the CPP file isn't compiling correctly because I get errors about NSString from NSObjCRuntime.h.

I understand them, but I want to know how others get round this issue. I'd like to be able to have my C++ files with CPP extension. Should I be looking towards settings in the Xcode project on how to treat CPP files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Xcode should treat `cpp` files as C++ by default. Make sure you don't have one of special Objective-C-only defines, such as `__OBJC__`, defined manually somewhere. As for `Availability.h` specifically, it doesn't require Objective-C (it's just preprocessor stuff) so the problem will presumably be elsewhere.

It is definitely possible to use OpenGL from `.cpp` files, compiled as C++, as I do it in my iOS project.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that you have a prefix header that includes Objective C headers. If that's the case, you should surround these with `#ifdef __OBJC__`.

Comment: Hey, thanks - I checked, but I'm quite familiar with the prefix file - the OBJC check is already in place. It seems to be that some CPP files go through fine (ones that are less integral and are imported at a deeper level, by fewer files), and others struggle.

Answer (score 0):

I found it - QuartzCore.h being eventually included, for CATransform3D. I forgot I intended to replace this with an alternative.